# How do you draw ray diagrams with virtual objects?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Consider Fig 1.

[image: **Fig 1**: Note that the image correspond to question 40-9]

I am confused about how you draw the ray diagrams for the virtual object $O'$.

The three rays for real objects for a concave lens are:

1. A parallel ray from the object diverges from the focus on the same side.
2. A ray from the object converging from the object will become parallel.
3. A ray that goes to the x-axis from the object will continue on as is.

There are 2 rays for the virtual object, which seems to be

1. A parallel ray that is the same height as the object from the opposite side of the object will diverge from the focus on the side the ray came from.
2. A ray that goes from the x-axis of the lens to the object continues on.

I don't understand when and why you start on the opposite side of the object. Why do these rules exist and when do you use them?